# Verifying the result of this complex integral (not integrable analytically)

Tags: complex-analysis

Could someone verify that the following result is correct?

$$\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C(0,1)} \frac{1}{e^z - 1 - z} dz = -\frac{2}{3}$$

($C(0,1)$ represents the unit circle)

I am attempting to use the expansion of the function as a Laurent series in combination with Cauchy's Integral Formula to get this result. If somebody could verify that I have done this correctly and also let me know if there is a nicer way to evaluate this, it would help greatly.

Thanks,
Helen.

Comment: What does the bound C(0;1) mean? The unit circle?

Comment: Yes, apologies if that isn't clear, I will edit the question.

Comment: Don't have time to write out a full answer, but if you're integrating around the unit circle (and not the punctured unit disk), Mathematica numerically evaluates that integral to  -0.05555....i. Which, looking at the residues, is -1/18i.

Comment: Mathematica is then wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^z-1-z=\frac{z^2}2+\frac{z^3}6+\ldots=\frac{z^2}2\left(1+\frac z3+\ldots\right)\implies$$

$$\frac1{e^z+1-z}=\frac2{z^2}\left(1-\frac z3+\frac{z^2}9-\ldots\right)=\frac2{z^2}-\frac2{3z}+\frac29-\ldots\implies$$

the function's residue at zero is $\;-\frac23\;$ and thus your result is correct. So good job!

Comment: You should probably also argue why $z=0$ is the only pole inside the unit circle.

Comment: @mrf Thank you. Did you mean the asker should argue that? Yes, I think she should...but on the other hand it's almost trivial, isn't it? I mean, even using the above power series we can see the only pole at all of the function is at zero.

Comment: It's not entirely trivial. Some estimation is required. (There are certainly other poles. For example close to $2.0888 \pm 7.4615i$.)

Comment: @mrf Thank you. May I ask how did you get that pole?

Comment: The poles can be expressed in terms of Lambert's W-function. I asked Maple to give me a numerical approximation.

Comment: @mrf Thank you. I asked WA and it said there's only one pole. Besides, the real part of $\;e^z-1-z\;$ with the value you give indeed seems to be zero...but not quite. I wonder whether there is a way to find out *for sure* analytically (without machines) about the existence of other poles but zero.